# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale - error while plotting adjacency matrix from igraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, igraph

I want to plot the adjacency matrix of a graph as a checkerboard. The code works ok with graphs created using functions like the built-in ´make_star´, but fails when using graphs created from adjacency matrices in csv files.

The csv file used on this test [can be found here](https://github.com/andandandand/MILS2D/blob/master/data/starGraphAdjMatrix.csv)

```
require(igraph)
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

require("igraph")


loadGraph <- function(dataPath)
{

  loadedDF <- read.csv(dataPath,
                       header=FALSE,
                       sep=',', #separate by comma
                       quote="'", # quote by '
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                       check.names = FALSE)

  #selects numeric values, drops the rest
  loadedDF <- loadedDF[sapply(loadedDF, is.numeric)]

  rownames(loadedDF) <- colnames(loadedDF)
  loadedMat <- as.matrix(loadedDF)

  #we use the rownames to index deletions
  g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(loadedMat) %>%
    set_vertex_attr("label", value = 1:nrow(loadedDF))


  return(g)
}

plotAdjMatrix <- function(graphToPlot){

  gAdjMatrix <- as.matrix(as_adj(graphToPlot))

  logMatrix <- (gAdjMatrix == 1)

  matData <- melt(logMatrix)

  g <- ggplot(data = matData,
              aes(Var2, Var1)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value, 
                  color = value)) + 
    coord_equal() + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "black", "FALSE" = "white")) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "white", "FALSE" = "black")) + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.grid = element_blank()) +
    guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE) +
    scale_y_reverse()

  print(g)
}

## Test #1 
g1 <- make_star(5)

# this works
plotAdjMatrix(g1)

## Test #2
g2 <- loadGraph("./data/starGraphAdjMatrix.csv")

# this fails
plotAdjMatrix(g2)
```

This is what g1 looks like

```
g1
IGRAPH b93c150 D--- 5 4 -- In-star
+ attr: name (g/c), mode (g/c), center (g/n)
+ edges from b93c150:
[1] 2->1 3->1 4->1 5->1
```

And this is g2:

```
> g2
IGRAPH e338cdb DN-- 5 8 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/n)
+ edges from e338cdb (vertex names):
[1] V1->V2 V1->V3 V1->V4 V1->V5 V2->V1 V3->V1 V4->V1 V5->V1
```

Looking at this, I had the idea of renaming the vertices in ´g2´ to ´1, 2, 3, ...´, and tried removing the line:

```
 set_vertex_attr("label", value = 1:nrow(loadedDF)
```

to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the issue is in `scale_y_reverse`. When you load the data from the csv file, the column names are V1, ..., V5, and the labels in the `y` axis also are such. Then, apparently, `scale_y_reverse` fails because it tries to reverse non-numeric values while treating them as numeric.

One way to fix this is to replace

```
gAdjMatrix <- as.matrix(as_adj(graphToPlot))
```

with

```
gAdjMatrix <- unname(as.matrix(as_adj(graphToPlot)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on this reduced example but it breaks other parts of the code, as the graph needs to be labeled to perform vertex/edge deletion. I tried creating a function to prep the graph for plotting ´unnameGraph <- function(graphToPlot){
  
  gAdjMatrix <- unname(as.matrix(graphToPlot))
  
  return(gAdjMatrix)
}´, but it still outputs "error: discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: I updated the answer. Apparently I'm suggesting to use `unname` in a very similar place as you tried, but it does work to me.